# HTML5 video: hide custom controls when native ones are re-activated

Tags: html, video, custom-controls, html5-video

Is there an HTML5 video(/audio) event for when the user re-enables the default browser controls?

Presently, I have the `controls` property enabled on the element, then remove it with javascript and show my custom controls. But what if the user uses the video context-menu and clicks "Show Controls" for the default browser controls to appear. I want to be able to honor that, and hide my controls in that event (maybe they prefer controls they are used to).

Is there a good way to toggle my controls when the native controls are toggled?

(watching for the `controls` attribute being added and removed doesn't seem like it will work. Re-enabling them adds the property back, but hiding the controls again does not remove the property. -- in chrome16)

---

**EDIT**: `var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];`

With hidden controls (initially and when set by context-menu):

```
v.getAttribute('controls') // null 
v.controls // false
```

With native controls shown by context menu:

```
v.getAttribute('controls') // '' in Chrome, "true" in FF9 (string)
v.controls // true
```

since the attribute is actually changing on the element, DOMAttrModified could work for the supporting browsers, yeah? (FF and Opera). Would this mean `setInterval` and checking `v.controls` for the others?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your users, but I doubt this happens a lot. So setInterval could add overhead for something that's rarely done. You might try using a related event to check for controls, like mousemove.

```
v.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
  customControls.style.display = (v.controls) ? 'none' : 'block';
}, false);

// Or New jQuery
$(v).on('mousemove', function(){ ...same... });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are immediate siblings after your video tag, you could do it with CSS:

```
video[controls] + #controls.custom {
    display: none;
}
```

which should work in all browsers that support video.